# how to show disk percentage in specific folder

Tags: linux, bash, shell, terminal

I have an problem with `df -h` in Linux , and I needed to make output in percent with specific folder size. In my case the folder is `/opt`.

Also how can I make the output only in folder `/opt` and usage in percent.

I have tried with another command like: `du -sch /opt`

Here is the [output from df -h](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LhaiJ.jpg) and this is the [output from du -sch /opt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PsBga.jpg)

So, can I make output from `df -h` with specific folder `/opt` and disk usage only?

I'll appreciate it if you guys can help me.

Comment: The percentage of `df` is that of the usage of the disk. For folders, what do want to the percentage represent: the part of the usage each folder represent within the  `/opt` folder ?

Comment: i mean how to grep usage in /opt and use% from output df -h

Comment: Add the desired output....

Answer (score 0):

Solve with this:

```sh
df -hl /opt | awk 'NR == 2{print $5}' | tr -d '%'
```